# List all td nodes with empty content

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I am using java 1.6. I am having the xml strcuture like below.

> ```
> - <table column="6" row="22">
> - <tr>
>   <td bold="true" class="header" font="Arial Narrow" size="9">Jinesh</td> 
>   <td align="Right" bold="true" font="Arial Narrow" size="9">2007</td> 
>   <td align="Right" bold="true" font="Arial Narrow" size="9">2008</td> 
>   <td align="Right" bold="true" font="Arial Narrow" size="9">2009E</td> 
>   <td align="Right" bold="true" font="Arial Narrow" size="9">2010E</td> 
>   <td align="Right" bold="true" font="Arial Narrow" size="9">2011E</td> 
>   </tr>
> <tr>
>   <td font="Arial Narrow" size="9" /> 
>   <td font="Arial Narrow" size="9" /> 
>   <td font="Arial Narrow" size="9" /> 
>   <td font="Arial Narrow" size="9" /> 
>   <td font="Arial Narrow" size="9" /> 
>   <td font="Arial Narrow" size="9" /> 
>   </tr>
> ```

Now I want to list all the td node with empty content such as  in the second  tag does not have any contents.Currently I am using the below Xpath expression to list out all the td nodes.

```
//table//tr//td[@font='Arial Narrow' and @size='9']
```

But the above expression list all the td nodes whether it is empty or not.
Can anybody please help me with xpath expression to list all td nodes with empty content?

Answer (score 4):

You can look for empty nodes by testing for an empty value as follows. Optionally, you can add `normalize-space()` to discard any whitespace encountered:

```
//td[normalize-space(.)='']
```

**Edit**

> Re:  If I want to list the td nodes if all the children td node of parent tr node is empty

```
//table/tr[not(td[normalize-space(.)!=''])]/td
```

Basically, find a tr where there are no non-empty child td's, and then navigate to the child td's.
There is no need to apply the must be empty filter to the `td`s again since we've already confirmed this at the `tr` level. It would also be possible to test this in a 'positive' fashion by counting the empty td's and all td's and testing, but I feel the negative is easier (viz no non-empty td's)

Comment: SturatLC: I am using Java1.6 and using Xpath expression mentioned in the question. In that case would the above exression work? and possible expression will be //table//tr//td[@font='Arial Narrow' and @size='9' and normalize-space(.)='']?

Comment: I've used basic XPath 1.0 functionality. Yes, testing for the `@font` and `@class` attributes will also work. You can possibly also shave one of the double slashes, viz `//table//tr/td`, given that the Html elements are usually structured as `table/thead (or tbody)/tr/td`

Comment: Is the expression  //table//tr//td[@font='Arial Narrow' and @size='9' and normalize-space(.)=''] is correct?

Comment: Stuart:In the above expression If I want to list the td nodes if all the children td node of parent tr node is empty. In the expression , defined in the answer if atleast one of td is empty it would still list that td node?Can we do this requirement using one single expression ?

Comment: Stuart:In the above expression If I want to list the td nodes if one or two the children td node of parent tr node are not empty but rest of them are empty. then is that possible using one single xpath expression ?

Comment: `count(normalize-space(.)!='') <= 2`

Comment: Stuart:I am not able to use the above expression in the Xpath. Here is the way I have used the expression //table/tr[count(normalize-space(.)!='')>1]/td  But the above expression gave an error saying below javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Can not convert #BOOLEAN to a NodeList!

Comment: Ok got it!!! here is the expression //table/tr[count(td[normalize-space(.)!=''])<2]/td